# How to load pictures from specified folder in winforms and how to drag these images to somewhere in forms

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have searched over Google and i found only drag and drop options for single images.Also in case of loading images only one images is loading into a picture box.

But I want to load images from a specified folder to winforms and i want to drag and drop these images to somewhere

Comment: And you thought about a listbox's drag drop events.. Together with a picture box? What do you want exactly? Drop images somewhere??

Comment: Drop images =>drop images may be in picture box

Comment: Loading images from specified folder  to picture boxes dynamically

Comment: An answer has been provided, this is a duplicate. Just use code like: pic = New PictureBox; pic.Location =...; this.Controls.Add(pic); in a x for loop and y for loop. You really need to read a book.